# K&R exercise 3-1

Tags: c, binary-search

> ```
> int binsearch(int x, int v[], int n) 
> {
>     int low, high, mid;
>     low = 0;
>     high = n-1;
>
>     while (low <= high)
>     {
>         mid = (low+high)/2;
>
>         if (x < v[mid])
>             high = mid -1;
>         else if (x > v[mid])
>             low = mid + 1;
>         else
>             return mid; /* found match */
>     }
>
>     return -1; /* no match */ 
> }
> ```
>
> Exercise 3-1. Our binary search makes two tests inside the loop, when
> one would suffice (at the price of more tests outside.) Write a
> version with only one test inside the loop and measure the difference
> in run-time.

This is the code I wrote :

```
int binsearch(int x, int v[], int n)
{
    int lh[2] = {0, n-1}, a[2] = {-1, 1}, mid;

    while (lh[0] <= lh[1])
    {
        mid = (lh[1] + lh[0])/2;

        if (x != v[mid])
            lh[x < v[mid]] = mid + a[x > v[mid]];
        else
            return mid;
    }

        return -1;
}
```

But they have about the same run-time? Why didn't removing one of the if statements reduce it?

Comment: You didn’t only remove one conditional, you also added indexing expressions. You were supposed to remove the the test “at the price of more tests outside”, which you didn’t do.

Comment: I think you can rewrite the code to do the lower bound search, then you need one more test after the loop. See here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/286441/151754

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance is expected to be pretty much the same as the original.

In the most common case (`x != v[mid]`) the first code computes:

- `x < v[mid]`
- `x > v[mid]` (half the time, when the first condition is false)
- Either `high = mid -1` or `low = mid + 1`

The second code computes:

- `x != v[mid]`
- `x < v[mid]` and `x > v[mid]` for indexing `lh` and `a` respectively.

That hasn't reduced the complexity; in fact it's slightly increased it.

I think that what the exercise is looking for is that you can find the smallest value *greater than or equal to `x`*.  Then after the loop, test whether that element actually is `x`.

I wouldn't expect to see a significant performance difference there either, but such a version would more *reusable*.  It's often useful in binary search to locate the index where the sought element *would be*¹, so it makes sense to build search from such a version, and when we have that position, to test whether the value actually is present at that position.

---

A subtlety that's present in both versions looks like this:

> ```
>        mid = (low+high)/2;
> ```

When `low` and `high` get large, their sum can be too big to represent in an `int`, and we get Undefined Behaviour.  This means that literally anything is allowed to happen, and that's not a good thing.

The way to avoid this, given that we know `low` and `high` are both positive, is to compute `mid` by adding half the difference:

```
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
```

That's mathematically the same, but computationally very different (in particular, no overflow can occur).

---

¹  Frequently we want to insert a value if it's not already there - perhaps if we're building a cache, or counting occurrences.